# automatic coloring of pre defined names in a report

Tags: formatting

I am coloring certain names and content in a report

Rather than individually coloring each name I would like to pre-define the content through some coding so that the moment the word is typed it gets highlighted in the pdf output after compiling

Kindly guide

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\begin{document}
                \begin{center}{\large \textbf{HANDING / TAKING OVER}}\end{center}
            \begin{description}         

\item {\textbf {\fbox{AON for CHT}}}
\item 11 Nov 2019
\subitem \fcolorbox{black}{green}{Preetha} check progress with IFA
\item 12 Nov 2019
\subitem \fcolorbox{black}{green}{Preetha} to liaise with IFA
            \end{description}
\begin{description}         
\item {\textbf {\fbox{AON for DEO}}}
\item 11 Nov 2019

\subitem \fcolorbox{black}{green}{Preetha} check progress with IFA
\item 12 Nov 2019
\subitem \fcolorbox{black}{green}{Preetha} to liaise with IFA

            \end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could create a new command in the preamble like

```
\newcommand{\Preetha}{\fcolorbox{black}{green}{Preetha}}
```

To use it in text, simply type

```
\Preetha
```